How to resolve "User does not have CONNECT privilege" error in pgAdmin?
I’m using pgAdmin4 on Windows.
I don’t understand how I can resolve this error.
To connect, I use Heroku Database Credentials.
It’s not impossible to create a table or check if there are any changes in the Heroku database.
So I have this error : -- No SQL could be generated for the selected object.
And all databases not connected
In the pgadmin tool, how do I give the user “discount” connect privileges (and table read/write privileges) to the database “discount”?
Thank you
